# How to use Dom::interval(x1,x2) in script?

Tags: matlab, mupad

I am using Matlab R2014a.

I need to find the answer to a set of inequalities and then use it in a script.
I used `solve([eq1,eq2],x)` but the answer is a MuPad syntax so I can't change it to a double or float to use in other calculations.
Is there an alternative way to solve system of inequalities, or a way to extract information from Dom::Interval(x1,x2)?

```
syms x
eq1= x>0 ;
eq2= x<3 ;
solve([eq1,eq2],x)
```

Output is:

```
"Dom::Interval(0, 3)"
```

and unusable for scripts.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to solve a system of equations while constraining the variables to a given set of ranges, you're better off using [`assume`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html) to set assumptions for each variable. For example:

```
>> syms x;
>> eq1 = x>0;  % Lower constraint
>> eq2 = x<3;  % Upper constraint
>> solve(sqrt(x^2-4)==0, x)  % An equation with 2 solutions

ans =

  2
 -2

>> assume(eq1 & eq2)  % Constrain x
>> solve(sqrt(x^2-4)==0, x)

ans =

2  % Only the solution that satisfies the constraints is returned
```